# Cucumber JVM Undefined Step Not resolving

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber-jvm

I am having issue with Cucumber JVM not being able to pick up the step definitions. I do have @CucumberOptions in the Runner file. My feature file does have @smokeTest tag as well.
Still the issue persists for me. Please help!I've been trying to resolve this for few days now.

Maven and Java version:

Apache Maven 3.0.4 
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.

Project structure:

1. Demo --> src --> test --> java --> com.smoke.test --> Runner.java | SmokeTestStepDef.java
2. Demo --> src --> test --> resources --> featureDemo.feature

Runner file:

package com.smoke.test;

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format={"pretty","html:reports/test-report"},tags= "@smokeTest")

public class Runner {
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cumcumberdemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: How do you write your .feature? Because it is on the right path, but seems that cucumber can't identify the steps, could you add in your question?

Comment: @PedroHenrique : Do you mean what is the Gherkin script in the feature file?

Comment: Yes, one time I had a problem like this, and the error was on the .feature file

Comment: Feature: Add two numbers

  Scenario: Validate addition of two numbers 
     Given I have a calculator
     When I add 2 and 3 
     Then the result is 5

Comment: @justCurious Can you please edit your question with your actual feature file (including cucumber tag if any)?

Answer (score 1):

Move `featureDemo.feature` under `src/test/resources/com/smoke/test`.

As Eugene mentioned, it looks like a glue issue but from your comments, there seems to be another feature file in your project that's hiding the problem that it's actually the feature file that cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define your glue path in @CucumberOptions as well. This is where your step definitions reside. It is described [here](http://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/CucumberOptions.html#glue--).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eugene S. Tried that as well. Did not work. I did my research on StackOverflow before posting this question.

Comment: @justCurious have you tried changing your tags to `tags = {"@smokeTest"}` (with curly braces)?

Comment: Yup, still does not work. Removed tags altogether as well and still the issue persists!

Comment: Nope. I'm using IntelliJ (CE) and this is what I get on Right click --> Run on feature file -
1 Scenarios (1 undefined)




3 Steps (3 undefined)
0m0.000s



Undefined step: Given  sample feature file is ready





Undefined step: When  I run the feature file

Comment: @justCurious well, if it says "undefined" that means that cucumber can't find the steps definition. make sure you set it correctly.

Comment: Yes, this is what the problem is- cannot find Step Defs and I'm not sure why.
When you say "set it correctly" , what do you mean? Please advice. Also, please see the project structure etc posted on the initial posting of mine.

Comment: @justCurious To me it looks like Cucumber runner can't find the tests glue code (feature file steps implementation). When I said "set it correctly" I mean that you must make sure Cucumber knows where the glue code is. Usually it is done by setting the "glue" parameter in the CucumberOptions but you said that you tried it already.

Comment: @justCurious your project structure looks fine to me. I would just go through trivial things again. Like making sure you didn't make any silly typos and the feature steps have proper names.

Comment: Yep tried that already:
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:featureDemo.feature",
        format={"pretty","html:reports/test-report"},
        tags= "@smokeTest",
        glue = "com.smoke.test/SmokeTestStepDef.java")

public class Runner {
}

Comment: @justCurious the glue path should not include the testStepDef filename. Just the directory itself. In your case: glue = {"com.smoke.test"}

Comment: I'm using a very simple example. Double checked Step Def regex (IntelliJ auto generates the skeleton). Very weird! Maybe its maven. On doing mvn clean install it does not even load the gherkin in feature file:
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running CucumberTestDemo.ParserTest
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.082 sec

Results :

Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: updated to  glue = {"com.smoke.test"} . Same result :(